# Using JQuery to process GET request of Transloc API

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JQuery to access Transloc's API (https://www.mashape.com/transloc/openapi-1-2#!documentation). I have not used JQuery or this API before. If anyone could shed some light on this I would appreciate it.

Comment: Please do some basic research about the libraries, tools and technologies you want to use before asking a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't test this as I don't have a key but it should work in theory.

Using the endpoint you linked to. Change the url for what you need.

```
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        beforeSend: function (request)
        {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-Mashape-Authorization", <mashape-key>);
        },
        url: "https://transloc-api-1-2.p.mashape.com/agencies.json?agencies=12%2C16&geo_area=35.80176%2C-78.64347%7C35.78061%2C-78.68218&callback=call",
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
            //use data
        },
        error: function(data) {
            //handle error
        }
});
```